# Consolidate data table factor levels in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a very large data table, one column of which is "ManufacturerName".  The data was not entered uniformly, so it's pretty messy.  For example, there may be observations like:

```
ABC Inc
ABC, Inc
ABC Incorporated
A.B.C.
...
Joe Shmos Plumbing
Joe Shmo Plumbing
...
```

I am looking for an automated way in R to try and consider similar names as one factor level.  I have learned the syntax to manually do this, for example:

```
levels(df$ManufacturerName) <- list(ABC=c("ABC", "A.B.C", ....), JoeShmoPlumbing=c(...))
```

But I'm trying to think of an automated solution.  Obviously it's not going to be perfect as I can't anticipate every type of permutation in the data table.  But maybe something that searches the factor levels, strips out punctuation/special characters, and creates levels based on common first words. Or any other ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: data.table refers to a particular R class that uses the data.table package. As far as I can tell, your question has nothing to do with it (in which case it should be taken out of the tags on the post).

Comment: I'm asking how to do something to a data table, how does that have nothing to do with data tables?  I didn't know if the package has anything extra pertinent to my question. I guess if it doesn't, we can just consider it as a data frame.

Comment: Ok. Hard to tell without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `stringdist` package. For starters, you could do something like this:

```
library(stringdist)

x <- c("ABC Inc", "ABC, Inc", "ABC Incorporated", "A.B.C.", "Joe Shmos Plumbing", "Joe Shmo Plumbing")
d <- stringdistmatrix(x)
#    1  2  3  4  5
# 2  1            
# 3  9 10         
# 4  6  7 15      
# 5 16 16 16 18   
# 6 15 15 15 17  1
```

For more help, see `?stringdistmatrix` or do searches on StackOverflow for fuzzy matching, approximate string matching, string distance functions, and `agrep`.